# Steps for using Google custom search API in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-custom-search

I am trying to use Google custom search API in my .NET project. 
I have an API Key provided by my company.
I have created a custom search engine using my Google account and copied the 'cx' value.

I am using the following code:

```
string apiKey = "My company Key";
string cx = "Cx";
string query = tbSearch.Text;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a test!");

string result = webClient.DownloadString(String.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={0}&cx={1}&q={2}&alt=json", apiKey, cx, query));
```

I am getting the following error: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. "

I have tried the following code too:

```
Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CustomsearchService svc = new Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CustomsearchService();
svc.Key = apiKey;

Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest listRequest = svc.Cse.List(query);
listRequest.Cx = cx;
Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.Data.Search search = listRequest.Fetch();

foreach (Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.Data.Result result1 in search.Items)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", result1.Title);
   Console.WriteLine("Link: {0}", result1.Link);
}
```

Here I get the following exception at Fetch():

Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Access Not Configured [403]
Errors [Message[Access Not Configured] Location[ - ] Reason[accessNotConfigured] Domain[usageLimits]

Is CX parameter required?
Am I getting the error because I am using the Key provided by my company and using the CX parameter from 
custom search engine using my Google account?

Is there any other way of getting 'cx'? We don't want to display Google ADs.

Thank you very much in advance for help.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure if you are still interested in this.

To get results without ads you need to pay for it.
[Info @ Google](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72326&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=1pte6z18mbci6&cbrank=1)

and yes the cx is required because it specifies the google custom search engine that you want to use to search.
you can create a custom search engine from [This google page](http://www.google.com/cse/create/new)

and here is the current code to retrieve search results for the current api version 1.3.0-beta

```
        string apiKey = "Your api key";
        string cx = "Your custom search engine id";
        string query = "Your query";

        var svc = new Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CustomsearchService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { ApiKey = apiKey });
        var listRequest = svc.Cse.List(query);

        listRequest.Cx = cx;
        var search = listRequest.Fetch();

        foreach (var result in search.Items)
        {
            Response.Output.WriteLine("Title: {0}", result.Title);
            Response.Output.WriteLine("Link: {0}", result.Link);
        }
```

Hope  this helps

Answer (score 13):

Instead of,

```
var search = listRequest.Fetch();
```

But now it does not supports Fetch() method, rather you need to use Execute() method.

```
var search = listRequest.Execute();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var listRequest = svc.Cse.List(query);
```

error !!!
you should use :

```
var listRequest = svc.Cse.List();
```

and then :

```
listRequest.Q=query
```