# Google Custom Search .NET API Compile issue with Fetch method

Tags: c#, .net, google-custom-search

I am attempting to use the Google CustomSearch API for .NET using sample code from the following locations:

- [Steps for using Google custom search API in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880921/steps-for-using-google-custom-search-api-in-net)
- [How can I do a search with Google Custom Search API for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040824/how-can-i-do-a-search-with-google-custom-search-api-for-net/11141158#11141158)
- http://astrocoder.com/search-using-google-custom-search/

The basic code in it's simplest form looks like:

```
string apiKey = "my-api-key";
string cseKey = "my-cse-id";
string query = "search query";
var bcsi = new BaseClientService.Initializer { ApiKey = apiKey };
var css = new CustomsearchService(bcsi);
var listRequest = css.Cse.List(query);
listRequest.Cx = cseKey;
Search search = listRequest.Fetch();
```

However, when I attempt to compile this, I am getting the following error:

```
'Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest' does not 
contain a definition for 'Fetch' and no extension method 'Fetch' 
accepting a first argument of type 
'Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest' could be found
```

As far as I can tell, I have all of the required library files (I used NuGet to install the Google APIs). When I view the API documentation, I do not see a `Fetch()` method, however, all of the sample code I have been able to find shows the `listRequest.Fetch()` method call.

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/customsearch/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Customsearch_1_1v1_1_1CseResource_1_1ListRequest-members.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Fetch() you can use the following.

```
Search search = listRequest.Execute();
```

The fetch() api has been replaced after version 1.4 but the sample code has not been updated yet.

Comment: Thanks; that seems to be working, however, now I'm getting a error from the Google API: 

Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Invalid Value [400] Errors [Message[Invalid Value] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]]

I assume this means either my apiKey or CSE ID is incorrect, but the "Location" field in the error is blank.

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to use the "search engine ID" and I was mistakenly using the "search engine project ID".