# Google Api Custom Search Example

Tags: c#, api, google-custom-search

I've just begun working with C# and the Custom Search API.
I've included the library and now I want to get some output, some results by entering a query.
My question: 
    could someone give me a simple example, please? 
I need such an example like this one on the following link ->
 *https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted*
Not with the Discovery API, but with the Custom Search API (Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1).
Or do you possibly know a tutorial how to build such programs, maybe?

Thanks a lot! Kind regards.

Valeria

Comment: I found this on another post:-

http://stackoverflow.com/q/14880921

Hope it helps.